Does Karate have integration with GitLab?
Does Karate have integration with GitLab CI? I searched on the internet but I could not find any detailed resource on how to integrate Karate with GitLab.
Could anyone help? Thank you in advance!

there seem to be plenty of info here on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+gitlab
